# React Native Switch being changed by other Switch and MultiSlider

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a project where I am trying to create a settings screen. I have two `Switches` and a `multiSlider` on this screen. My first `Switch` keeps changing to on if the other `Switch` is true/turned on or if the slider is moved. I've been trying to figure out why this is happening, but I can't seem to figure it out. I would appreciate any help or advice on how to get this to work or what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

```
...
export default function SettingsScreen() {
    const [settingsData, setSettingsData]: any  = React.useState({
      switch1: false,
      multiSlider: [0,100],
      switch2: false,
    })
   
    useEffect(() => {
    if (settingData?.getSettings?.switch1) {
  /*Note: settingData?.getSettings?.switch1 is coming from my backend using graphql*/
      settingsData.switch1 = settingData?.getSettings?.switch1
    }
  if (settingData?.getSettings?.switch2) {
  /*Note: settingData?.getSettings?.switch2 is coming from my backend using graphql*/
      settingsData.switch2 = settingData?.getSettings?.switch2
    }
    }), [settingData?.getSettings]

    const sectionData = [
      {title: 'Preferences', 
      data: [
        {_id: 'switch1', type:'Switch1', value:false},
        {_id: 'multiSlider', type:'multiSlider', single:false},
      ]}, 
      {
        title:'Privacy',
        data: [
          {_id: 'switch2', type:'switch2', value:false}
        ]
      }
    ]
 
    const info = ['multiSlider']
   
   
    return (
      <View>
          <SectionList
            sections={sectionData}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.type+index}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
                <View  style={{
                    flex: 0,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    justifyContent:'space-between',
                    paddingHorizontal: 15,
                    paddingVertical:0,
                    }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize:17,}}>{item.type}</Text>
                {!info.includes(item.type) ?
                <View>
                    <Switch
                        onValueChange={ value  => 
                          setSettingsData({
                            ...settingsData, 
                            [item._id]:value,
                          })}
                        value={settingsData[item._id]}
                        />
                    <StatusBar style='auto' />
                </View>
                :
                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center',flexDirection: 'row', width:290, paddingRight:10}}>
                    <View style={{width:35}}>
                    {item.single === false &&
                    <Text>{settingsData[item._id][0]}</Text>
                    }
                    </View>
                    <MultiSlider
                        trackStyle={{backgroundColor:'#bdc3c7', height:3.5}}
                        selectedStyle={{backgroundColor:'#e33062'}}
                        values={ item.single ?
                          [settingsData[item._id][1]] : settingsData[item._id]}
                        sliderLength={200}
                        onValuesChange= {x => 
                          setSettingsData({ 
                            ...settingsData, 
                            [item._id]: x,
                        })}
                        min={settingsData[item._id][0]}
                        max={settingsData[item._id][1]}
                        step={1}
                        allowOverlap={false}
                        snapped={true}
                    />
                
                {item.single === false &&
                <View style={{width:45,}}>
                 <Text style={{paddingLeft:20}}>{settingsData[item._id][1]}</Text>
                 </View> 
                }
                </View>
                }
                </View>
                </View>
            )}
            renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
                <Text style={{ fontSize:19, paddingVertical:10}}>{title}</Text>
            )}
            />       
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Comment: It seems like MultiSlider and Switch use the same _id.
There is a colon between Switch and MultiSlider maybe you forgot an condition ?

Comment: @Michael Bahl, Hi, that colon goes with ```{!info.includes(item.type) ?```. How could/ Why are they be using the same _id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/multislider-and-switch?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=performancemax&gclid=CjwKCAjw5_GmBhBIEiwA5QSMxGJF14U2zeGa-NFdRRWfZRB2h_cp3fh3M7vOKgUhyCOqrKDyFuVkDBoCiqEQAvD_BwE), I can’t reproduce the behavior you describe.
Can you perform test and let me know if this works a expected.

Comment: @Michael_Bahl Thank you for your response! The example you gave me worked. After seeing the differences in our codes, I tested my code without the ```useEffect(() => { }), [settingData?.getSettings]```,  and it works. Do you know what could be happening or how I could still have a preset/ use ```useEffect``` without having this same problem

Comment: You should never manipulate state with value assignment like ``` settingsData.switch1 = settingData?.getSettings?.switch1``` .
Always use the regarding setter ```setSettingsData```